# TypeError: Array.from is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm following the Angular.io [documenation](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/quickstart.html) to write a simple "Hello World" app with Angular 2. Once the app runs in the browser, Angular 2 throws a `TypeError` from `angular2/src/browser_adapter.js`.

Everything seems to be setup correctly. Any idea what the issue is?

Console:

```
TypeError: Array.from is not a function
    at createArrayFromMap (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/src/facade/collection.js:61:42)
    at Function.MapWrapper.values (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/src/facade/collection.js:100:47)
    at _createListOfBindings (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/src/di/injector.js:769:36)
    at Function.Injector.resolve (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/src/di/injector.js:403:16)
    at Function.Injector.resolveAndCreate (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/src/di/injector.js:420:41)
    at _createAppInjector (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/src/core/application_common.js:291:39)
    at http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/src/core/application_common.js:257:31
    at Zone.run (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.js:118:17)
    at Zone.run (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/src/core/zone/ng_zone.js:165:42)
    at NgZone.run (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/src/core/zone/ng_zone.js:112:40)BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ :3000/node_modules/angular2/src/dom/browser_adapter.js:71
```

all.babel.js ( gets complied to es5 all.js):

```
import {Component, View, bootstrap} from 'angular2/angular2'

@Component({
  selector: 'helloworld'
})
@View({
  template: `<h1>Hello World!</h1>`
})
class HelloWorld {

}


bootstrap(HelloWorld)
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Angular 2 Hello World</title>
    <script src="./node_modules/rx/dist/rx.all.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="./node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.js"></script>
    <script src="./node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="./dist/all.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <helloworld></helloworld>
     <script type="text/javascript">
      System.config({
        baseURL: '/'
      , defaultJSExtensions: true
      , paths:  {
          'angular2/*': './node_modules/angular2/*.js' // Angular
        , 'rx': './node_modules/rx/dist/rx.all.js'
        , 'all': './dist/all.js'
        }
      })

      System.import('all')
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Replicate with https://github.com/agconti/angular-2-hello-world.

Comment: [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) is new with ES6 and will require a polyfill for older browsers, such as [those provided by babel](http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/).

Comment: `Array.from` is a new feature in ES6. Is it possible that you are doing something that is forcing the code to run as ES5? Also, per the Mozilla docs, it is not currently supported by IE, Safari, and Opera: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#Browser_compatibility

Comment: @JackA. I don't think so. Also, I've tried setting my system.js transpilier to babel with the same effect

Comment: @JonathanLonowski adding in the traceur runtime works. is there away I use angular 2 without including it?

Comment: See also : http://caniuse.com/#search=Array.from

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to get Angular 2 to run in the browser I had to include the traceur runtime:

```
<script src="https://github.jspm.io/jmcriffey/bower-traceur-runtime@0.0.87/traceur-runtime.js"></script>
```

This was necessary even after I setup my Systems.js config to use Babel as a transpiler.

Comment: Currently Angular2 is dependent on traceur's runtime polyfills. They are working on [removing that dependency](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/3694), but it is a WIP.

Comment: @JesseGood thanks for clarifying. That was my next question.